# $E^{*} \otimes E^{*}$ is canonically isomorphic to $Hom^2(E × E , \mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

This question was asked in exercise of my linear algebra course and I am not able to prove part (ii) of it.

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector space ( over $\mathbb{R}$).

(I) What is the defining characteristic of the tensor product $ E\otimes E$.

(II) Prove that $ E^* \otimes E^*$ is canonically isomorphic to $Hom^2( E \times E; \mathbb{R})$ .

Ist part I have done.

$Hom^2( E × E , \mathbb{R}) $  is the space of bilinear maps $ f: E× E \to \mathbb{R}$.

I am not able to construct a map which could act as isomorphism.

Can you please help me with this?

I have been following the textbook of Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: Maybe include your solution of Question 1. Then prove that $Hom^2(E\times E,\mathbb R)$ satisfies this defining characteristic. By using this universal property you maybe dont have to write down an isomorphism explicitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the map
$f\colon E^* \times E^* \to \mathrm{Hom}(E\times E;\mathbb R)$
mapping $(\alpha,\beta)$ to a homomorphism $f(\alpha,\beta)$ acting on $(v,w) \in E \times E$ as $f(\alpha,\beta)(v,w) := \alpha(v)\beta(w)$.
This is bilinear by definition, so it extends to a linear map $\tilde{f}\colon E^* \otimes E^* \to \mathrm{Hom}(E \times E; \mathbb R)$ such that $\tilde{f}(\alpha \otimes \beta) = f(\alpha,\beta)$. Its kernel is trivial, and $\dim(E^* \otimes E^*) = \dim \mathrm{Hom}(E\times E;\mathbb R)$, so $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: can you please tell how kernal of $\tilde{f}$ is trivial ?  Also how is dimension $( E^* \times E^* ) = $ dimension of $Hom^2 ( E \times E , \mathbb{R}) $. If I am not wrong, dimension of $E^* \otimes E^{*}) = n^2$.  But how to compute dimension of $ Hom( E× E; \mathbb{R})$? Please help.

Comment: As for injectivity, you want $f(\alpha,\beta)$ to vanish when applied to any pair $(v,w)$. Then necessarily either $\alpha=0$ or $\beta = 0$, and hence in both cases $\alpha \otimes \beta = 0$. The kernel of $\tilde{f}$ is then trivial. The dimension of $\mathrm{Hom}(E \times E; \mathbb R)$ is just $\dim (E \times E)\dim \mathbb R = \dim E^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve part II by using part I. I assume your answer to part I was something like this:

The tensor product $T:=E\otimes E$ is uniquely determied by the following property:

There exists a bilinear map $\otimes:\, E\times E \to T$ such that for every bilinear map $f:E\times E\to Z$ there exists a unique linear map $\tilde f:\,T\to Z$ such that $f=\tilde f\circ \otimes$.

---

Lets prove that $Hom^2(E\times E,\mathbb R)$ satsifies the universal property of $E^\ast \otimes E^\ast$. We define $\otimes:E^\ast \times E^\ast\to Hom^2(E\times E,\mathbb R)$ by $\otimes(\alpha,\beta)(v,w)=\alpha(v)\beta(w)$. This map is bilinear and if $f:E^\ast \times E^\ast\to Z$ is any bilinear map then we define $\tilde f:\,Hom^2(E\times E,\mathbb R)\to Z$ by $\tilde f(g)=f(g\circ\iota_1,g\circ \iota_2)$ where $\iota_i:E\to E\times E$ is the inclusion of $E$ into the $i$-th factor ($i=1,2$). Then $f=\tilde f\circ\otimes$ and this in fact defines $\tilde f$ uniquely.